# AWS CLI and JMESPath filter and select on nested properties

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli, jmespath

I want to use the CLI tool, to retrieve the distribution-id of a CloudFront distribution with a specific cname/alias.

This is what I came up with:

```
aws cloudfront list-distributions --query "DistributionList.Items[?Aliases.Items!='null']|DistributionList.Items[?contains(Aliases.Items,'cname.cdn.mycompany.com') == 'true'].{Id:Id}"
```

I'm not an expert at JMESPath, and I don't understand why my query doesn't return a result. A distribution with the specified domain as alias exists.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're very close! A few things though:

- `null` is not `'null'`
- After the pipe you'll be working with the results of the first expression
- like `null`, `true` is not a string (`== true` is also redundant)

[jmespath.org](http://jmespath.org) Has a live editor that you can use to test out expressions. Here's a simplified json we can use to test this case:

```
{
    "DistributionList": {
        "Items": [
            {
                "Id": "foo",
                "Aliases": {
                    "Quantity": 1,
                    "Items": [
                        "cname.cdn.mycompany.com"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "Id": "bar",
                "Aliases": {
                    "Quantity": 1,
                    "Items": [
                        "cname.cdn.othercompany.com"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "Id": "baz",
                "Aliases": {
                    "Quantity": 0
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Let's start with the first part of the expression. The only fix you need is taking the quotes off null:

```
DistributionList.Items[?Aliases.Items!=null]
```

Which will successfully filter out elements without `Items` under `Alias`. Here is what you would get back if you stopped here, and what you'll have to work with after the pipe:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "foo",
    "Aliases": {
      "Quantity": 1,
      "Items": [
        "cname.cdn.mycompany.com"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "Id": "bar",
    "Aliases": {
      "Quantity": 1,
      "Items": [
        "cname.cdn.othercompany.com"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Note that there is no `DistributionList.Items` anymore.

So now we want to filter for a specific CNAME. Lets leave out the tautology `== true`.

```
[?contains(Aliases.Items, 'cname.cdn.mycompany.com')]
```

So the full expression now is:

```
DistributionList.Items[?Aliases.Items!=null] | [?contains(Aliases.Items, 'cname.cdn.mycompany.com')]
```

And your result is the successfully filtered list:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "foo",
    "Aliases": {
      "Quantity": 1,
      "Items": [
        "cname.cdn.mycompany.com"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Now if you want the Id's of the matching elements, just add `.Id` to that last expression. If you know there will only be one, you can just select that element with another pipe and `[0]`.

```
DistributionList.Items[?Aliases.Items!=null] | [?contains(Aliases.Items, 'cname.cdn.mycompany.com')].Id | [0]
```

And you get the Id you want!

```
"foo"
```

Comment: When perfoming the query on command line I had to change the quotes around domain name to \` \`

Answer (score 1):

To add, I found it out without the pipe.

`aws cloudfront list-distributions --query "DistributionList.Items[?contains(Aliases.Items, 'cname.cdn.mycompany.com')].Id" --output text`